# Does Select linq function preserve List collection order?

Tags: c#, linq, select, collections

I think I know the answer to this question, but I wanted to double check with people who perhaps know more than me. So here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
var t = 10;
var conditions = new List<Func<int, Tuple<bool, string>>>
{
    x => new Tuple<bool, string>(x < 0, "Bad"),
    x => new Tuple<bool, string>(x > 100, "Bad"),
    x => new Tuple<bool, string>(x == 20, "Bad"),
    x => new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "Good")                
};
var success = conditions.Select(x => x(t)).First(x => x.Item1);
```

I'm checking for multiple conditions on some data. Now, if my linq statement returns me "Good" can I be certain that all of the conditions were run and that none of them evaluated to true? In other words, would the collection returned by `Select` have the same order as the original collection. I think it would. Am I wrong?

Comment: can you show us the source code you use to check the data? My answer is "usually" but there are some cases where it will return a results before checking everything

Comment: This is the code i use. I changed the conditions to simple int statements just for readability.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `Select`, or all LINQ operations?  Some have a defined and documented order, some have a particular order in implementation, but don't document it, and some have undefined orderings in both documentation and implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net is open sourced now. [Check it out](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,919) for `IList` `First()` just takes first element. And [Select](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,362) just enumerates list, so order is preserved.

As for your particular `First(x => x.Item1)` case it will turn into.

```
foreach (TSource element in source) {
    if (element.Item1) return element;
}
```

where source is similar to that IEnumerable (I've removed some code, which is not used in your case)

```
public Func<int, Tuple<bool, string>> Current {
    get { return current; }
}

public override bool MoveNext() {
    var enumerator = conditions.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        Func<int, Tuple<bool, string>> item = enumerator.Current;
        current = item(t);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the underlying collection type - if the type has a defined order (like `List`), then yes it will preserve order.  If the order of items in not defined (like `Dictionary`, `HashSet`) then the "First" item is not predictable.